# haxelib run <lib> get user directory

Tags: haxe, haxelib

I'm trying to create some commands for my haxe library, but I have a problem. In fact, I want to generate some files and directories in the directory where the command `haxelib run <mylib> <command>` is send.

But, when it runs it generates the data in my lib directory (where the *run.n* is). My path is the following :

```
Sys.getCwd() + "/myfile.txt"
```

I also tried

```
"myfile.txt"
```

Always the same thing. Perhaps that's because I installed my library with `haxelib git`?

*flixel-tools* has a command that generates something too, but that's directly with `flixel tpl -n 'name'`. They don't use `haxelib run flixel`. 
That's why it works for them ?

Thank you if you have an idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Using haxelib](http://haxe.org/doc/haxelib/using_haxelib#getting-the-directory-of-haxelib-being-called) wiki page:

> When run.n is called from haxelib, the current working directory will
>   be set to the library directory (eg. /usr/lib/haxe/lib/somelib/1,0/).
>   The directory of haxelib being called will instead be passed as an
>   extra argument, put at the end of the argument array.

Example usage:

```
var haxelibDir = Sys.getCwd();
var userDir = Sys.args().pop();
Sys.setCwd( userDir );

// Now copy a sample file from the haxelib dir to the user's current dir:
var content = File.getContent( '$haxelibDir/tpl/myfile.txt' );
File.saveContent( '$userDir/myfile.txt', content );
```